# Имеем ли мы право разрабатывать персональной программное обеспечение для банкоматов (NCR, Diebold, Wincor...)?

Tags: юридические-аспекты

Насколько мне известно, банкоматы (NCR, Diebold, Wincor...) поставляются производителями с программным обеспечением. Так не можем ли мы сами создавать ПО для банкоматов? Имеем ли мы право разрабатывать персональной программное обеспечение для банкоматов (NCR, Diebold, Wincor...)?

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: Имеем ли мы право разрабатывать ПО для android или PC .... :))

Comment: Вам надо обсуждать эти вопросы с производителями. Android / PC это одно дело, а например Томограф или Вертолет - слегка другое.